# Подстановка текста по клику js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Необходимо написать скрипт, чтобы при нажатии на валюту сверху вписывался текст в поле ниже, где сейчас usd. То есть при классе active на bitcoin должно быть написано btc и т.д.
js, jquery

```
<div class="payment_options row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-6 col-xl-3">
                <div class="partner_img">
                  <i class="icon lg icon-dw-bitcoin"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 col-xl-3">
                <div class="partner_img">
                  <i class="icon lg icon-dw-etherum"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 col-xl-3">
                <div class="partner_img">
                  <i class="icon lg icon-dw-litecoin"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 col-xl-3">
                <div class="partner_img">
                  <i class="icon lg icon-dw-dogecoin"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 col-xl-3">
                <div class="partner_img">
                  <i class="icon lg icon-dw-tether"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 col-xl-3">
                <div class="partner_img">
                  <i class="icon lg icon-dw-ripple"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 col-xl-3">
                <div class="partner_img">
                  <i class="icon lg icon-dw-tron"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="paym_form">
              <div class="payment_form row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                  <div class="modal_info">
                    The payout amount in ETH will be calculated according to the ETH to RUB exchange rate at the
                    moment of the payout being processed.
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                  <div class="payment_form_inner">
                    <div class="pfi_top row">
                      <div class="col-md-auto">
                        <div class="pfi_qr"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md">
                        <div class="pfi_options">
                          <div class="radio_accent">
                            <input class="d-none" id="depos_option_11" name="depos_option" type="radio" value="500">
                            <label for="depos_option_11">500
                              <span class="currency">USD</span></label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="radio_accent">
                            <input class="d-none" id="depos_option_21" name="depos_option" type="radio" value="1000">
                            <label for="depos_option_21">1000
                              <span class="currency">USD</span></label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="radio_accent">
                            <input class="d-none" id="depos_option_31" name="depos_option" type="radio" value="5000">
                            <label for="depos_option_31">5000
                              <span class="currency">USD</span></label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="radio_accent">
                            <input class="d-none" id="depos_option_41" name="depos_option" type="radio"
                              value="10000">
                            <label for="depos_option_41">10000
                              <span class="currency">USD</span></label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="radio_accent">
                            <input class="d-none" id="depos_option_51" name="depos_option" type="radio"
                              value="50000">
                            <label for="depos_option_51">50000
                              <span class="currency">USD</span></label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="radio_accent">
                            <input class="d-none" id="depos_option_61" name="depos_option" type="radio"
                              value="20000">
                            <label for="depos_option_61">20000
                              <span class="currency">USD</span>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="radio_accent_big">
                            <div class="col-auto">
                              <div class="radio_accent">
                                <input class="d-none" id="depos_option_c1" name="depos_option" type="radio">
                                <label for="depos_option_c1"></label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col radio_custom_input">
                              <input disabled id="depos_option_custom1" name="depos_option_value" type="number">
                              <label for="depos_option_custom1">USD</label>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикрепите ваш код к сообщению, тогда можно будет посмотреть

Comment: Прикрепил, посмотрите

Comment: вы пытались написать этот скрипт? приведите попытки и покажите, что не получается, разберемся. А если нет, так вряд-ли поможет кто-то. Здесь же не биржа фриланса, чтобы за вас бесплатно код писать

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение, не каких изменений в коде делать не нужно, просто вставить этот код после вашего и все будет работать

```
(function ($) {
  var obj = {
        bitcoin: 'btc',
        etherum: 'eth',
        litecoin: 'ltc',
        dogecoin: 'doge',
        tether: 'usdt',
        ripple: 'xrp',
        tron: 'trx'
  }
  $('.partner_img').on('click', function () {
    try {
      var type = $('.icon',this).attr('class').match(/([a-z]+$)/ig);
      if (type) $('.currency').text(obj[type]);
    } catch (e) {}
  })
}(jQuery));
```